# automatically generate nuget package with symbols on build

Tags: .net, build, nuget

I have a C# project (.net 6.0) from which I want to automatically create a nuget whenever I (re-)build it.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-the-dotnet-cli) it says:

> To automatically run `dotnet pack` when you run `dotnet build`, add the
> following line to your project file within `<PropertyGroup>`:
>
> ```
> <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
> ```

I tried it and it works, but, no symbols (`.pdb` files) are added. How can I do this?

- The command `dotnet pack --include-symbols` can be used for that, but how do I tell the `.csproj` file to use that command instead of `dotnet pack`?
- `dotnet pack --include-symbols` will generate two nuget packages, one ending with `.nupkg` and one with `.symbols.nupkg`. The former does not contain the `.pdb`, the latter does. I want just one file generated (the `.nupkg` one without `.symbols` prefix) which contains both `.dll` and `.pdb`.

---

I tried the following:

- remove `GeneratePackageOnBuild` property
- add target to project: `<Target Name="BuildNuget" AfterTargets="AfterBuild"><Exec Command="dotnet pack --include-symbols"/></Target>`

But now when I run `dotnet build`, I run into an infinite loop: (Unfortunately it's German, but you can see it just repeats.)

> ```
> Wiederherzustellende Projekte werden ermittelt...
> Alle Projekte sind für die Wiederherstellung auf dem neuesten Stand.
> MyProject-> C:\Users\...\MyProject\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\MyProject.dll
> Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 für .NET
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
>
>   Wiederherzustellende Projekte werden ermittelt...
>   Alle Projekte sind für die Wiederherstellung auf dem neuesten Stand.
>   MyProject-> C:\Users\...\MyProject\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\MyProject.dll
>   Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 für .NET
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
>
>     Wiederherzustellende Projekte werden ermittelt...
>     Alle Projekte sind für die Wiederherstellung auf dem neuesten Stand.
>     MyProject-> C:\Users\...\MyProject\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\MyProject.dll
>     Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 17.0.0+c9eb9dd64 für .NET
>     Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
>
>       Wiederherzustellende Projekte werden ermittelt...
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack) it says:

> The dotnet pack command builds the project and creates NuGet packages.

So if I have `dotnet pack` as a command after build, I will just get into an infinite build stack.
On the same page the options for `nuget pack` are listed. One of them is `--no-build`.

Changing the target to

```
<Target Name="BuildNuget" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="dotnet pack --no-build --include-symbols"/>
</Target>
```

solves the issue.